# Mocking advantages over nUint

Tags: asp.net, rhino-mocks

I am new to testing.I have to test some  C# classes.Kindly let me know what is mocking and 
why some mocking framework like Rhino mock is preferred over nUint?

Comment: Should that be NUnit?  If so, they fit well together and are certainly not mutually exclusive.  Mocking is a tool to help unit testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you are talking about NUnit. Mocking frameworks is nothing that you use *instead* of a unit testing framework; you use them *together*. In short, the purpose of a mocking framework is to mock (or fake) functionality that the tested code is depending upon, but that is not the code that you currently want to test.